# Guest WiFi with additional Access Point?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, home-networking, wireless-access-point, fritzbox

I wanted to set up a guest wifi for friends and family when they come over so it's easier to manage. I found an option to enable a guest wifi on my fritzbox with a separate password and enabled that. Seems to work fine.

My question now is: For better wifi signals, I installed an old, spare router as an access point in my appartment. Will the guest wifi now also be available on this access point or can it only be accessed using the fritzbox, thus making the signal very poor in some rooms?

Comment: What model is the old spare router, and what model Fritzbox? How are the 2 routers connected to each other?

Comment: One of the LAN outputs of the Fritzbox 3490 runs to one of the LAN outputs of the D-Link Dir-300 in order to use it as an access point. The D-Link Dir-300 then gets the access point WiFi running and also connects my smart tv via LAN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The D-Link Dir-300 supports only one SSID (Wifi network name) and does not support guest networks, so it is unable to service your private Wifi and your guest Wifi networks at the same time. It will not automatically copy the Wifi configuration and guest network(s) of your main router.

So, unfortunately, that means the guest Wifi network will not be available on the second Access Point.